# What design pattern (if so) did I apply? How can I further improve it?

Tags: design-patterns, c, polymorphism, pointers, method-overloading

Suppose I have a `program.c` that needs `element_123` to do some operations, and `element_123` can be accessed by including `agent.h`

```
/*program.c*/
#include "agent.h"

uint32_t element_123 = 0;
agent_get_element_123(&element_123);

uint32_t data = element_123 + some_data;

/*do operations...*/
```

`element_123` may be implemented by different chips in different projects, and only one chip exists in a project.

```
/*chipA.c*/
#include "agent.h"

void chipA_get_element_123(uint32_t* output)
{
    //dummy code to get element_123 from chip A
}

agent_t agent = {&chipA_get_element_123};
```

---

```
/*chipB.c*/
#include "agent.h"

void chipB_get_element_123(uint32_t* output)
{
    //dummy code to get element_123 from chip B
}

agent_t agent = {&chipB_get_element_123};
```

My goal is to use `agent.c` to provide a unique interface to `program.c`. In other words, `agent_get_element_123` is a compile-time polymorphic function that depends on chip.

```
/*agent.h*/

typedef struct
{
  void (*get_element_123)(uint32_t* output);
}agent_t;

void agent_get_element_123(uint32_t* output);
```

---

```
/*agent.c*/

extern agent_t agent;

void agent_get_element_123(uint32_t* output)
{
  agent.get_element_123(output);
}
```

My questions are:

1. The minimum knowledge that `program.c` needs to know is `agent_get_element_123`, and having nothing to do with `agent_t`. However, `chipA.c` and `chipB.c` need to know it. Is there a way to decouple `agent_t` from `program.c` while keeping its relation with `chipA.c` and `chipB.c`?
2. Does this technique deserve to be called a design pattern? If so, what is this design pattern called?
3. This technique undoubtedly is just one of many approaches out there. What's are differences between this technique and other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call this compile-time polymorphism.

Architecturally this is a Platform Independence Layer, or a System Services Layer.

Design pattern wise, its a **Plugin**.

---

without `agent_t`:

```
/*agent.h*/

void agent_get_element_123(uint32_t* output);
```

```
/*chipA.c*/
#include "agent.h"

void agent_get_element_123(uint32_t* output)
{
    //dummy code to get element_123 from chip A
}
```

```
/*chipB.c*/
#include "agent.h"

void agent_get_element_123(uint32_t* output)
{
    //dummy code to get element_123 from chip B
}
```

And no need for `agent.c`

You may need to have an `init()` function to perform module level setup (and perhaps even a `deinit()` or equivalent for teardown).

Comment: A voice telling me that prefixing filename to function name increases code quality, and I always follow this rule. However; after reading this answer, I feel that a little offense may be a good choice sometime.

Comment: @AndyLin I don't see how that is anything more than Hungarian Notation applied to function names. I can see how it might be useful if a file represents a module, as that would be a form of namespace management encoding the module name into the function names for context. However here `agent.h` represents the agent module, and the two files `chipA.c` and `chipB.c` are implementations of that module. If it makes you happier call them `agent.c` in seperate folders `\chipa\agent.c` and `\chipb\agent.c`

Comment: I noticed a big difference between these two approaches. With my approach, `program.c` has no need to compile to adopt new chip, because `program.c` does not depend on source code of chips. Is it correct?

Comment: Why would `program.c` need to be recompiled? It depends solely on `agent.h`, not the implementations. Of course it will need to be relinked based on which implementation you choose.

Comment: I think your approach is better than mine in any aspect.